# Add a php loop to a series of divs with incremental class names

Tags: php

I'm building an html page that I'd like to add a php loop to.

At present the code looks like this:

```
<?php $i = 0; ?>
  <div class="element-item <?php echo mysql_result($value, $i);?>">...</div>

<?php $i = $i+1; ?>
  <div class="element-item <?php echo mysql_result($value, $i);?>">...</div>

<?php $i = $i+1; ?>
  <div class="element-item <?php echo mysql_result($value, $i);?>">...</div>
```

However as every div is exactly the same, apart from ($value, $i) with $i rising in value by 1 each time, I'd like a way of declaring upfront that the loop will contain x amount of divs (in this case 3 but in reality over 100) and that each time it repeats itself $i rises by +1

All help greatly appreciated...

Answer (score 0):

Using while loops may solve the problem... make sure $query = mysql_query("")

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)){
  $value = $row["columnname"];
  $i++;
  echo "<div>YOUR CONTENT HERE</div>"
}
```

Please use prepared statements (http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php). mysql_* is deprecated

Answer (score 0):

Try somethings like this:

```
<?php 
  for ($i = 0; $i <$yourLimit, $i++){
   echo ' <div class="element-item'.$i.'">...</div>'
  } 
?>
```

Comment: Thanks for this scaisEdge however the line <?php echo mysql_result($value, $i);?> cannot be edited as $value is dynamic. Are there any other methods you could recommend? Thanks